# Multidimensional FFT in python with CUDA or OpenCL

Tags: python, cuda, opencl, fft

I have been browsing around for simple ways to program FFTs to work on my graphic card (Which is a recent NVIDIA supporting CUDA 3.something).
My current option is either to learn C, then that special C version for CUDA, or use some python CUDA functions. I'd rather not learn C yet, since I only programmed in high-level languages.
I looked at pyCUDA and other ways to use my graphic card in python, but I couldn't find any FFT library which could be use with python code only.
Some libraries/project seem to tackle similar project (CUDAmat, Theano), but sadly I found no FFTs.

Does a function exist which could do the same thing as `numpy.fft.fft2()`, using my graphic card?

EDIT: Bonus point for an open source solution.

Answer (score 4):

There's [PyFFT](http://packages.python.org/pyfft), which is [open-source](http://github.com/Manticore/pyfft) and based on Apple's (somewhat limited) [implementation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OpenCL_FFT/Introduction/Intro.html). Disclaimer: I work on PyFFT :)

Comment: I'll check it out as soon as I have some time!

Comment: You can also have a look at [reikna](https://github.com/Manticore/reikna), which is a collection of GPGPU algorithms in development and includes slightly improved ``pyfft`` code, along with other features.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, ArrayFire has a [2-D FFT for Python](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/python/group__fft.htm).

Disclaimer:  I work on ArrayFire.

Comment: Wow! This looks really nice and I will definitely try it out.
The only problem I see with this library (sorry for not mentioning it in the question), is that it's not open source. The main reason I switch from an astrophysics-specific language to Python was because I could keep using it after I leave college.
I'll check the limitation of the free license, but it seems to be what I'm looking for!

Comment: Free for single GPU usage, http://www.accelereyes.com/products/arrayfire_licensing

Comment: ArrayFire no longer has a Python interface.